# Multiply matrices using list comprehensions

Tags: python

Can anyone pls help me understand how this matrix multiplication really works?

```
def matrix_mul(a, b):
    return [[sum(i * j for i, j in zip(r, c)) for c in zip(*b)]
        for r in a]

a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [[5, 1], [2, 1]]
c = matrix_mul(a, b)
```

Comment: list comprehension is simply a shorter syntax for a for loop which appends elements to a new list. I suggest you break it down to a regular for loop, and also check and print what each expression does. I would suggest changing the input so each element is unique and its easier to follow, e.g.: `b = [[5, 6], [7, 8]]`

Answer (score 3):

Your expression has essentially three nested list comprehensions (although in fact one of them is a generator expression).  If you replace them with explicit loops, add some appropriately named variables for the lists which are being built up, and add some print statements, then you can see what is going on:

```
def matrix_mul(a, b):

    matrix_out = []
    for r in a:
        print("    Input row of a", r)
        row_out = []
        for c in zip(*b):
            print("        Input column of b", c)

            products = []
            for i, j in zip(r, c):
                print("            Values to multiply:", i, j)
                inputs = i, j
                products.append(i * j)
                
            print("        List of products:", products)
            print("        Sum of products:", sum(products))
            row_out.append(sum(products))
            
        matrix_out.append(row_out)
        print("    Row of answer", row_out)
        print()
    print("Answer", matrix_out)
    return matrix_out


a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [[5, 1], [2, 1]]
c = matrix_mul(a, b)
```

Gives:

```
    Input row of a [1, 2]
        Input column of b (5, 2)
            Values to multiply: 1 5
            Values to multiply: 2 2
        List of products: [5, 4]
        Sum of products: 9
        Input column of b (1, 1)
            Values to multiply: 1 1
            Values to multiply: 2 1
        List of products: [1, 2]
        Sum of products: 3
    Row of answer [9, 3]

    Input row of a [3, 4]
        Input column of b (5, 2)
            Values to multiply: 3 5
            Values to multiply: 4 2
        List of products: [15, 8]
        Sum of products: 23
        Input column of b (1, 1)
            Values to multiply: 3 1
            Values to multiply: 4 1
        List of products: [3, 4]
        Sum of products: 7
    Row of answer [23, 7]

Answer [[9, 3], [23, 7]]
```

To explain the `zip(*b)` using the example values:

```
b = [[5, 1], [2, 1]]
```

the `*` will make it expand the top-level list to a number of separate arguments

```
zip([5, 1], [2, 1])
```

And the zip will then yield a sequence of tuples consisting of the first element from each input list, then the second element of each input list (and so on, although in this case there are only two pairs), i.e.

```
(5, 2)
(1, 1)
```

In other words, the columns of `b`.

---

*(Note: because the input to `sum` in the original code is actually a generator expression rather than a list comprehension, it does not in fact produce a list of products, but rather generates a sequence of products that are consumed by the `sum` function one at a time. But aside from some efficiency gain in doing it this way, the effect is basically the same.)*

Comment: OP, this is an excellent answer! exactly what I thought of when writing my comment. try to look at this and see how you could have reached this result yourself, it will help you a lot in the future when trying to understand convoluted code.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Thanks for your comment.  I added an explanation of the `zip(*b)` because that might not be immediately obvious even when using explicit loops, but I think that all the rest of it is pretty self-evident once the list comprehensions are unpacked into explicit loops.

Comment: Thanks alanwi for the in detail explanation it really helped me to understand the code

Answer (score 0):

So by decalring :

`def matrix_mul(a, b):`

```
return [[sum(i * j for i, j in zip(r, c)) for c in zip(*b)]
    for r in a]
```

U are actually doing the following :

```
a = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
b = [[5, 1], [2, 1]]
```

First element of array B (5) multiplied by first element of array A (1) + snd element of array A (2) multiplied by first elem of array B[1] (2). So for obtain c u need to do :

```
c = [[9,3],[23,7]]
9 = a[0][0] * b[0][0] + a[0][1] * b[1][0]
3 = a[0][0] * b[0][1] + a[0][1] * b[1][1]
23 = a[1][0] * b[0][0] + a[1][1] * b[1][0]
7 = a[1][0] * b[1][0] + a[1][1] * b[1][1]
```

I think that this is the correct asnwer. Hope i helped you